# How to get Python to look at Sub-Folders?

Tags: python, directory, subdirectory

I am trying to create a python script that will look in  a series of sub-folders and delete empty shapefiles. I have successfully created the part of the script that will delete the empty files in one folder, but there are a total of 70 folders within the "Project" folder. While I could just copy and paste the code 69 times I'm sure must be a way to get it to look at each sub-folder and run the code for each of those sub-folders. Below is the what I have so far. Any ideas? I'm very new to this and I have simply edited an existing code to get this far. Thanks!

```
import os

# Set the working directory
os.chdir ("C:/Naview/Platypus/Project")

# Get the list of only files in the current directory
file = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir('C:/Naview/Platypus/Project'))
# For each file in directory
for shp in file:
    # Get only the files that end in ".shp"
    if shp.endswith(".shp"):
        # Get the size of the ".shp" file.
        # NOTE: The ".dbf" file can vary is size whereas
        #       the shp & shx are always the same when "empty".
        size = os.path.getsize(shp)
        print "\nChecking " + shp + "'s file size..."

        #If the file size is greater than 100 bytes, leave it alone.                  
        if size > 100:
            print "File is " + str(size) + " bytes"
            print shp + " will NOT be deleted \n"

        #If the file size is equal to 100 bytes, delete it.      
        if size == 100:
            # Convert the int output from (size) to a string.
            print "File is " + str(size) + " bytes"                    
            # Get the filename without the extention
            base = shp[:-4]
            # Remove entire shapefile
            print "Removing " + base + ".* \n"
            if os.path.exists(base + ".shp"):
               os.remove(base + ".shp")
            if os.path.exists(base + ".shx"):
                os.remove(base + ".shx")
            if os.path.exists(base + ".dbf"):
                os.remove(base + ".dbf")
            if os.path.exists(base + ".prj"):
                os.remove(base + ".prj")
            if os.path.exists(base + ".sbn"):
                os.remove(base + ".sbn")
            if os.path.exists(base + ".sbx"):
                os.remove(base + ".sbx")
            if os.path.exists(base + ".shp.xml"):
                os.remove(base + ".shp.xml")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this.  I'm a fan of [`glob`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html)

```
for shp in glob.glob('C:/Naview/Platypus/Project/**/*.shp'):
    size = os.path.getsize(shp)
    print "\nChecking " + shp + "'s file size..."

    #If the file size is greater than 100 bytes, leave it alone.                  
    if size > 100:
        print "File is " + str(size) + " bytes"
        print shp + " will NOT be deleted \n"
        continue
    print "Removing", shp, "files"
    for file in glob.glob(shp[:-3] + '*'):
        print " removing", file
        os.remove(file)
```

Answer (score 0):

Time to learn about procedural programming: [Defining Functions](http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/functions.html).

Put your code into a function with a path parameter and call it for each of your 70 paths:

```
def delete_empty_shapefiles(path):
    # Get the list of only files in the current directory
    file = filter(os.path.isfile, os.listdir(path))
    ...

paths = ['C:/Naview/Platypus/Project', ...]
for path in paths:
    delete_empty_shapefiles(path)
```

Bonus points for creating a function that performs the `os.path.exists()` and `os.remove()` calls.